# QT - bar graph- real time

Tags: qt

how can I make a graph and bar graph like this in qt?[I wanna visualize data changes as a bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soxtf.png)

Comment: You may want to start here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-barchart-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Use QWT library which is build on top of Qt. Look at the demos of QWT.